# How to get ordered key-value pairs from a map, given an ordered list of keys?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, elixir, key-value

Given a map, I want to sort the key-value pairs in a given order which I will provide via a list of all keys. Since maps are unordered collections I replaced the map with a keyword list. But now I'm struggling with sorting all its entries according to the given list of keys. If anyone knows solution to this problem in elixir please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) to map the sorted list of keys to the corresponding key-value pairs from your map:

```
ordered_keys = [:a, :b, :c]

map = %{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

Enum.map(ordered_keys, &{&1, map[&1]})
```

Output:

```
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
```

---

If you prefer, you can also use a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```
for key <- ordered_keys, do: {key, map[key]}
```

Comment: I believe they want the kw back, so it should be `&{&1, map[&1]}`,  and `do: {key, map[key]}` respectively.

Comment: Hi @Adam  I want kw or map back and I am not much familiar with elixir syntax. Could you guys please correct it to return map or kw?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @Aleksei Actually I do not know how to make use of comments added by you. Could you please elaborate it more. Thanks

Comment: `Enum.map(ordered_keys, &{&1, map[&1]})` or `for key <- ordered_keys, do: {key, map[key]}`. Both will return a sorted keyword list back.

Comment: I edited the question with what I think you want, and updated the answer (the same as Aleksei's suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
Enum.sort(keyword_list, fn {k, _v} -> k end)
```

Comment: Hi @potibas How could I pass key list here in which order  I want sorting of entries?